# Is there a way to get a fully executable string of the SQL that is about to be run by a Linq2Sql expression?

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, debugging

I know you can get the SQL, but it's paramterized without the parameters being visible. Can you get the "full" string, so to speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Guthrie created an add on, that works in the debugger.

[get it here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)

Comment: Ha as I was writing the qestion hazy memories of that tool started coming back - couldn't remember when and where - shoulda guessed Gu!

Comment: I get a lot of use out of it.  Sometimes I just don't recognize what my issue is in linq, but it is painfully obvious once I can run the actual SQL expression.

Comment: Although it does have negligible issues with localised dates